# how to set custom client id in react-ga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

i'm using `react-ga` in my app,every thing is ok but i want to change **Client id** of each device.this is how i **initialize** `react-ga`.

```
ReactGA.initialize('UA-11xxxxxx-x', {
    debug: true,
    titleCase: false,
    'cookieDomain': 'auto',
    gaOptions: {
        name: 'DyuserName',
        userId: 'DyuserId'
    }
});
```

normally in js we do like [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#disabling_cookies)
[image]

how can i change client id in react-ga

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the userId to DyuserId like below:

ReactGA.ga("set", "userId", "" + DyuserId);